# What is the correct way to close a second Application loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Form formOnThisMessageLoop = new Form();
        formOnThisMessageLoop.Show();

        Form formOnOtherMessageLoop = new Form();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {                                        
                Application.Run(formOnOtherMessageLoop);                    
            }
         );
        //Thread.Sleep(50);
        formOnOtherMessageLoop.HandleCreated += (obj, args) =>
        formOnOtherMessageLoop.Invoke(new Action(() => { formOnOtherMessageLoop.Close(); })); //Value Close() cannot be called while doing CreateHandle().
        Application.Run();                         

        Console.Read();
    }
```

I'm experimenting with various ways to close a form on a second message loop.  How can I synchronize my threads correctly in such a case?  Also, do I need to call `Application.Exit()` twice or is Form.Close() the best I can do?  I see Application.Run() keeping my dead thread alive.  That's my concern with it.  Assume the Main thread could live a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form.Close()` will exit that other message loop as long as the Form is passed in as a parameter to `Application.Run(formOnOtherMessageLoop)` as you have done.  If instead you wrote `Application.Run()` and called `Form.Close()` the application will not exit.

But why do you *need* another message loop?  Especially the way that you are doing it, because that will consume a thread pool thread to run said other message loop.

That's almost always a bad idea- this coming from someone who has worked with very latency-sensitive applications that were implemented using multiple message loops (usually poorly, with lots of bugs).

Comment: I have a loading form that displays in this second thread.  The GIF won't spin if it's on the same thread as the UI because the UI is spitting up a bunch of garbage.  So what you are saying is that I really need to offload the work done in the UI before firing off a second loop eh?  This will have to do for now because offloading the UI is a HUGE job...lots of Controls are created in super complex logic.

Comment: Yeah- do the hard work that the UI thread is bogging down on in a background thread, and use Invoke and BeginInvoke as needed to update the UI with status  (or better yet, use the BackgroundWorker class).

Comment: If it is loading the UI takes such a long time, you cant offload that to a background thread (interacting with controls needs to be done on the UI thread).  You should consider how to optimize that instead.  The usual culprit in WinForms is loading data to bind to dropdowns and grids and the like.  I'd look into getting a profiler to see what takes so long.

Comment: Yup, agreed.  That's why I say its a big job.  I will be doing all the above..I just need something to tell the users "hey yea I know this code sucks and its slow so please wait we are actually doing something not froze up"...until then

Comment: In that case your original plan might be the best you can do.  Don't forget to Invoke or BeginInvoke when calling across threads, and use it with extreme caution.